# Update content on an application with Powershell or WMI in Microsoft SCMM 2012 SP1

Tags: powershell, wmi, sccm-2012, application

While right-clicking an applications deployment type(s), we can select Update Content. Is there a way of doing this action using Powershell or a WMI-method?

Comment: WMI is to pull information from the system. I don't know the powershell option, however why not schedule this installed under the data source of the application to update the distribution points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some intense searching I found a solution. In the SCCM SDK there's a WMI class called [SMS_ContentPackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh949706.aspx), which has the public method Commit(). Using this I was able to update content on all applications, using the following Powershell-code on the server:

```
foreach($application in Get-CMApplication){
    $Get_WmiObject = @{
        'Namespace' = 'root\SMS\Site_<SiteCode>';
        'Class' = 'SMS_ContentPackage';
        'Filter' = "PackageID='$($application.PackageId)'";
    }
    (Get-Wmiobject @Get_WmiObject).Commit() | Out-null
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish this as well, and your answer doesn't appear to be working for me. I am able to run the commit method, but it doesn't update the package. When running Get-CMApplication, I see that the SDMPackageVersion does not change, and the SDMPackageXML still reflects the old content. When I hit "Update Content" through the SCCM console, those values are updated to reflect the new content.

Comment: That's odd, does the application get a new version-ID in the UI?

Comment: No - it doesn't - I just tested again to be sure. I then manually hit "Update Content" on the deployment type, and the revision number was increased by 1.

Comment: If you ommit piping the output to Out-Null, do you get a response? Also, I don't know if it matters, but this was done on SCCM 2012 SP1, are you using that as well?

Comment: Response is "returnvalue: 0" (with a bunch of other WMI fluff to go with it). It is on SCCM 2012 SP1.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using this powershell script to update the content of all applications, only caveat is, the revision always gets increased:

```
try
{
    Get-Wmiobject -Namespace "root\SMS\Site_<sitecode>" -Class SMS_Application -Filter "isLatest='true' and isExpired='false'" | foreach{
           $name = $_.LocalizedDisplayName
           echo "Application : $name"
           $dptypes = Get-CMDeploymentType -ApplicationName "$name"
           foreach ($dpt in $dptypes){
                $dptname = $dpt.LocalizedDisplayName
                echo "Deployment Type: $dptname"
                Update-CMDistributionPoint -ApplicationName "$name" -DeploymentTypeName "$dptname"
                }
           }
}
catch
{
    $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set-CMDeploymentType with -ContentLocation will force an update, even if the ContentLocation is set to the same as the original.

My code looks like this:

```
$app = Get-CMApplication -Name $PackageName
$depType = $app | Get-CMDeploymentType
$depType | Set-CMDeploymentType -MsiOrScriptInstaller -ProductCode $productCode -ContentLocation $PkgRead
```

The existing location can be trickier to determine - if you don't already know where it is, you can pull it out of the deployment type XML or WMI.